# How to implement JQuery and Bootstrap in Electron app

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular, electron

I packaged my Angular2-Electron app up after I figured it was ready for production and ran into an error on the way. The errors that came up was that my boot strap and JQuery wasn't able to be found. Right now i am loading it inside my index.html through node_modules. This worked great until I had to package it. What is the best way to load JQuery and bootstrap locally so that my electron app can find it?
The Error I am getting is **Error cannot find module** 
I understand the reason why, it's because when electron packs things up everything is moved to one file, I just can't figure out where and when to load up bootstrap and JQuery to that corresponding location

index.html:

```
 <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>

 <script src="../node_modules//bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

Answer (score 3):

Requiring alone is not enough to load jquery, you will have to additionally reference your file in a  tag:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');</script>
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should also make sure that all your paths are correct (you have a double / in your bootstrap.min.js reference)

Comment: Well it was working 100% before this, but I did this also and still get:

Comment: I understand the reason why, it's because when electron packs things up everything is moved to one file, I just can't figure out where and when to load up bootstrap and jquery to that corresponding location

Answer (score 0):

script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"

This links helps jquery to sync your project with bootstrap elements and works with internet connection only.